# Is the CES function increasing in its parameter?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$ and define
$$
f(x)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i^{\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}},
$$
where $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$.

**I would like to show that this function is increasing in $\rho$.**

Note that as $\rho\rightarrow -\infty$, $f$ collapses to a min function. Indeed, suppose that the minimum of $x$ is $x_1$. Then
$$
\frac{f}{\min_i x_i}=\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i^{\rho}}{\left(\min_i x_i\right)^\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \left(\frac{x_i}{x_1}\right)^{\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}.
$$
As $\rho\rightarrow -\infty $ this expression becomes 1 and so
$
\lim_{\rho\rightarrow-\infty}=\min_i x_i. 
$
A similar reasoning shows that $
\lim_{\rho\rightarrow\infty}=\max_i x_i. 
$
This seems to suggest that $f$ is increasing in $\rho$ but I haven't been able to write a formal proof. Taking the derivative introduces annoying terms.

Comment: Doesn't hold for $n=1$.

Comment: @user58697 Sorry meant to say that the $a_i$'s sum to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result turns out to be true and is related to generalized means. For a proof see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Proof_of_the_weighted_inequality